# Using regex to search text for country names, with and without spaces

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regex expression to search over a block of text to find all country names within the text. However a country name can contain spaces in it, so for example England could be United Kingdom, Great Britain, UK or GB.

So far the process that I have been following so far is;

1) First eliminate all words that do not start with a capital letter.

2) Then search for all lowercase letters preceding this

I created a basic expression for this;

```
[A-Z][a-z]+
```

This worked for countries with one word for a name.

However as I want to be able to capture country names with more than one word in it. I then used a pipe operator to be able to match multiple groups (|)

The process is now;

1) Eliminate all lowercase words by making the regex expression search only for words that begin with a capital letter for the first letter.(same as before)

2) Use pipe operator to match multiple groups;

2.1) Where group 1 will be used to match one or more lowercase letters preceding the first capital letter. (i.e. so I will be able to get the country name "China")

2.2) Where group 2 will be used to match one or more uppercase letters preceding the first capital letter. (i.e. so I will be able to get the country name "USA")

2.3) Where group 3 will be used to match for multiple words and spaces where the words can have capital letters, (i.e. I can get the country name "Papua New Guinea")

I have managed to achieve the first two groups (2.1 and 2.2) using the regex;

```
[A-Z]([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)
```

However when trying to achieve the third group I cannot get the results using the pipe operator as the pipe operator matches the first group set (2.1).

The regex expression I used for this was;

```
[A-Z]([a-z]+|[A-Z]+|[a-zA-Z\s]*)
```

Is there a way to check get the regex to match all the groups?

Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/EbYAaS/1) to my regex.

Comment: Could you describe an algorithm (in human-readable form) that you are going to use to extract the country name? It seem to be not an easy one (regardless of using of regex'es). You probably can take some list of all country names and to some (fuzzy) searching against this list…

Comment: As far as I see from your example the country names are by no means different from the rest of the text. So how do you want to tell them apart (no matter what method you plan to use)?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov I have edited as requested. I think what you are saying about creating a list of country names and then searching a against this list is something that I will need to do. Currently I have a db with all the country names in, I thought I could maybe get the country names from the regex and then search the database for the country name, using the value from the regex. However create aliases for certain countries within the database to make sure that they match up with the value from the regex. Do you think this is feasible?

Comment: @a_guest Just made some edits to question and regex. The aim was to extract all words with capital letters, then search a db that will have a list of country names, and compare each word. If a word value from the regex is equal to the country name in the db, then select that name from the db. However as mentioned above, the errors I was getting is that I cannot retrieve values from the regex that would have multiple words in the country name. Like "Papua New Guinea". But am thinking about making aliases in the the db tables for country name. So Papua would select "Papua New Guinea".

Comment: @mp252 If you have a database containing all the country names why would you even use a regex? You can simply select a name from the database and then check `name in text`.

Comment: @a_guest I just tried this, unfortunately did not work, as the way the countries db table is layed out. For example within a block of text I have Vietnam and United States. However when I used this method to select all country names from db, in the DB the United States is before Vietnam. So it returns true for that entry. However I want it to return Vietnam.

Comment: Could you just iterate over all country names from your database and check if this name is in text or not? You can even check where in the text this names appear like `text.find(country)`.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov This sort of works, however I have the problem of I want it only to return the value (country name) of the lowest index. I tried to append to a ```list``` and find the ```min``` value of that list, but then I am only stuck with index value of the string in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485744/using-regex-to-search-text-for-country-names-with-and-without-spaces?noredirect=1#comment72164015_42485744).

Assume you have a list of all countries like so:

```
countries = ['Russia', 'USA', 'United States of America', 'Zimbabwe']
# this should contain all the countries, I just show an example here
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
indexes = [text.find(country) for country in countries]
found_contries = [(index, country) for index, country in zip(indexes, countries) 
                  if index != -1]
```

Thus we make a list of tuples `(index, country)` for those countries actually found in the text (if it is not found, `text.find` return -1 and it's excluded from the list as per the condition `if index != -1`).

Then the country you need is just

```
min(found_contries)[1]
```

For example, let `text = "lala lalala Zimbabwe lala USA"`. Then

```
indexes
[-1, 26, -1, 12]

found_contries
[(26, 'USA'), (12, 'Zimbabwe')]

min(found_contries)[1]
'Zimbabwe'
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this worked. I never knew about the [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function, very handy.

Comment: @mp252 Good it works. You probably need to get some introductory course to get familiar with the rest of Python's basic features. For example, in my solution it is also used a feature that tuples are compared lexicographically (first element with first element, if equal, second with second and so on). This is why `min(found_contries)[1]` returns the correct answer. There are lots of such tiny hacks in Python that makes your life easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: I posted the following answer before the OP changed their question completely.**

You could use a regular expression binary `OR` operator (represented by `|`) to search for one of the list of country names and use the parentheses operator to place the matches in a "group":

```
(.*(China|United Kingdom|England).*)*
```

The internal `.*` catch any text surrounding or in between the country names. The external `*` will repeat the group matching until all country names have been matched.

On the [page you linked to](https://regex101.com/r/UudmQX/1), for example, you will only reference the matches in green (the "group" matches), not the full matches.

I recommend doing this programmatically. You would loop over a list of country names and search for them in your input string:

Simplified Python example:

```
all_country_names = ['China', 'United Kingdom', 'England']
found_country_names = []
input = 'In China there is the great wall.'
for name in all_country_names:
    if name in input:
        found_country_names.append(name)
```

Comment: this would work, but as @Toto has mentioned what about other countries, the list would become so long.

Comment: @mp252 Yes, the list would become very long, that's why I suggest to do it programmatically and not to use a regex.

Comment: @Qululu You can also create a (long) regex programatically so that's not a problem but if you're using only `|` operators in the regex you can equally use Python's `in` operator (not referring to efficiency here).